# accessing buttons of every layout

Tags: android, layout, button

what i need is to access the buttons of the clicked item(layout); this code works but just display all buttons,TextView,...of all layouts not the clicked one.
if you want to run this code you can add other layouts with buttons for the test
thank you for your help
here is my layout:

This is **activity_main.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ListView>
       <TextView        
          android:id="@+id/myTextView"    
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
         android:layout_height="25dp"    
         android:textSize="23sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

**Then my MainActivity:**

```
    package com.example.adapterlist;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Map<String, Integer> layoutIds = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    ArrayList<String> arrayForArrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
        java.lang.reflect.Field[] ID_Fields = R.layout.class.getFields();
        String []values=new String[ID_Fields.length];
        int[] resArray = new int[ID_Fields.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < ID_Fields.length; i++){
            try {
                resArray[i] = ID_Fields[i].getInt(null);
                values[i]=getResources().getResourceEntryName(resArray[i]);
                Log.v("resArray[i]  " , getResources().getResourceEntryName(resArray[i]));

            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
             listView.setAdapter(adapter);
             listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){







                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    iJustClickedAnItemInTheList((String) listView.getSelectedItem());


                }
             });
private void iJustClickedAnItemInTheList(String idname) {
        setContentView(layoutIds.get(idname));
        ArrayList<Button> allButtonsInLayout = getViewsFromViewGroup(findViewById(android.R.id.content), Button.class);
    }

    public static <T> ArrayList<T> getViewsFromViewGroup(View root, Class<T> clazz) {
        ArrayList<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
        for (View view : getAllViewsFromRoots(root)) 
            if (clazz.isInstance(view)) 
                result.add(clazz.cast(view));
        return result;
    }

    public static ArrayList<View> getAllViewsFromRoots(View...roots) {
        ArrayList<View> result = new ArrayList<View>();
        for (View root : roots)
            getAllViews(result, root);
        return result;
    }

    private static void getAllViews(ArrayList<View> allviews, View parent) {
        allviews.add(parent);
        if (parent instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)parent;
            for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++)
                getAllViews(allviews, viewGroup.getChildAt(i));
        }
    }
```

**And eventually my class MySimpleArrayAdapter:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
  private final Context context;
  private final String[] values;

  public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.troisieme, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.troisieme, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
    //ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    textView.setText(values[position]);
    // Change the icon for Windows and iPhone
    String s = values[position];


    return rowView;
  }
}
```

Comment: is now my question clearer?

Comment: Please be more clear. Do you want the ID names from all Views on a contentView when set? Eg on layout `someLayout` you have only a textView with ID `R.id.myTextview` and you want only `myTextview`?

Comment: the only idea i have seems to be ridicoulus: using a db that will store all buttons of each layout .....

Comment: But what exacly do you want? Please elaborate and give examples.

Comment: after i have display all layouts what i want is to get the buttons of every layout(when i click on it)

Comment: actually  i want  to allow the user to configure the buttons by putting on it an image that he wants so after he chooses a specific layout by clicking  on it i want him to see all the buttons of that specific layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the `Buttons` from a single layout:

```
public static <T> ArrayList<T> getViewsFromViewGroup(View root, Class<T> clazz) {
    ArrayList<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (View view : getAllViewsFromRoots(root)) 
        if (clazz.isInstance(view)) 
            result.add(clazz.cast(view));
    return result;
}

public static ArrayList<View> getAllViewsFromRoots(View...roots) {
    ArrayList<View> result = new ArrayList<View>();
    for (View root : roots)
        getAllViews(result, root);
    return result;
}

private static void getAllViews(ArrayList<View> allviews, View parent) {
    allviews.add(parent);
    if (parent instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)parent;
        for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++)
            getAllViews(allviews, viewGroup.getChildAt(i));
    }
}
```

from your `MainActivity` you call

```
ArrayList<Button> allButtonsOnCurrentLayout = getViewsFromViewGroup(findViewById(android.R.id.content), Button.class);
```

Now you have an `ArrayList` with all `Buttons` from the current layout. You can iterate the list and fetch their ID's with the reflection you already displayed, or show their tags, et cetera.

**Edit: My last attempt to help, extend the code below with your own**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Map<String, Integer> layoutIds = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    ArrayList<String> arrayForArrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        for(Field field : R.layout.class.getFields()){
            try {
                int id = field.getInt(null);
                String name = getResources().getResourceEntryName(id);
                layoutIds.put(name, id);
                arrayForArrayAdapter.add(name);
            } 
            catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void iJustClickedAnItemInTheList(String idname) {
        setContentView(layoutIds.get(idname));
        ArrayList<Button> allButtonsInLayout = getViewsFromViewGroup(findViewById(android.R.id.content), Button.class);
    }

    public static <T> ArrayList<T> getViewsFromViewGroup(View root, Class<T> clazz) {
        ArrayList<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
        for (View view : getAllViewsFromRoots(root)) 
            if (clazz.isInstance(view)) 
                result.add(clazz.cast(view));
        return result;
    }

    public static ArrayList<View> getAllViewsFromRoots(View...roots) {
        ArrayList<View> result = new ArrayList<View>();
        for (View root : roots)
            getAllViews(result, root);
        return result;
    }

    private static void getAllViews(ArrayList<View> allviews, View parent) {
        allviews.add(parent);
        if (parent instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)parent;
            for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++)
                getAllViews(allviews, viewGroup.getChildAt(i));
        }
    }
}
```

If this doens't help you, I do not know what will. Now use `allButtonsInLayout` to show the `Button` id's, or whatever it is you want to do with all the `buttons`.

Comment: See edit. But is what i described what you actually want, or have I misinterpreted you?

Comment: sorry i've got it i test it and i am going to see

Comment: it's the methode getAllViews thaat i don't have

Comment: i 've got an error with label and when i tried to replace by zero it's even worst...

Comment: Post error. What label? What did you replace by zero? Please, elaborate. I can't help you if you don't disclose any information.

Comment: what is exactly  R.id.label ?

Comment: Where do you see `R.id.label`? You're confusing me. And technically, it's an `int`.

Comment: Sorry! it isn't in your code but in mine.I tried to run the code and display allButtonsOnCurrentLayout on LogCat by using to string and it deosn' t show anything

Comment: With you i guess that the code runs perfectly  :-) but how ca i display the ArrayList<Button> allButtonsOnCurrentLayout as i've just written it i tried with log.v by adding toString() but it doesn't show anything

Comment: like that Log.v("button  " , allButtonsOnCurrentLayout.toString());

Comment: try 
`String s = ""; for (Button b : allButtonsOnCurrentLayout) s+= b.getId(); System.out.println(s);` Or Toast it, even better. However, thats another question, it's getting messy here.

Comment: Christiaan i don't understand your code .i am trying to run it but it doesn't

Comment: i got any answer from one of you but i do not  understand the answer i know the guy knows exactly his affair but the problem is the code isn't running

Comment: If I do not know the problem, I cannot help you. How am I supposed to fix "The code is not running"? For me it does, it works perfectly, does exactly what it's supposed to. You should learn Java and Android basics first, because it seems you haven't mastered them yet.

Comment: here is my new question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14519918/accessing-the-buttons-of-a-specific-layout of how i tried to make run

Comment: here is my new question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14519918/accessing-the-buttons-of-a-specific-layout of how i tried to make run and the problem is when i click on item of the list of the layouts the code just stop i guess it's the argument of the famous method "iJustClickedAnItemInTheList(String idname)" and don't hesitate if you 've got a tutorial of basics android or and java i know that i haven't a good level and i am ready to improve it